# скрыть часть option на bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

как в bootstrap в выподающем списке скрыть часть option ?
есть список

```
<select id="subcategories" class="selectpicker bs-select-hidden">
        <option value="">Выберите подкатегорию</option>
        <option value="ob" class="sok">Обычный</option>
        <option value="sv" class="sok">Свежевыжатый</option>
</select>
```

как при определенном условии скрыть

```
<option value="sv" class="sok">Свежевыжатый</option>
```

Answer (score 2):

Смотря какую часть нужно скрыть, например если нужно показать только 3 первых option, вот:

```css
select option:nth-child(n+4){
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<select class="browser-default custom-select">
  <option selected>Выбери число</option>
  <option value="1">Один</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
  <option value="4">Четыре</option>
  <option value="5">Пять</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Это не bootstrap!  bootstrap стилизует option из за чего способ с display: none для скрытия option не работает

Comment: тогда код в студию, без кода сложно о чем то говорить